# How to pass variable into curl

Tags: bash, shell, curl

There are other questions about putting the variable into curl command within the url.

I want to have a variable defined at the top of script to swap values like so:

```
# MODE=-v
MODE='-sS -w "\nEffective URL: %{url_effective} \nSize: %{size_download} \nTotal time: %{time_total} \nRedirect URL: %{redirect_url}"'
```

and use it among several curl requests like so:

```
PAGE=$(curl $MODE --include --location --config curl.config $TARGET1)
```

Unfortunately, none of the variations of quoting ($MODE or $TARGET1) or `${MODE}` I've tried causes the -w option to be accepted and appear at the bottom of $PAGE. It works fine when replacing `$MODE` with the long version.

How can this be made to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another (similar) way. Would also suggest you quote variables like *URI*. 
A second point is to be careful with upper-case variable names; as they can easilly crash with environment variables etc.

```
#!/bin/bash

url="$1"

w=("-sS"
"-w
Effective URL: %{url_effective}
Size         : %{size_download}
Total time   : %{time_total}
Redirect URL : %{redirect_url}"
)

page="$(curl "${w[@]}" --include --location --config curl.config "$url")"
```

Comment: Thanks for including the comment about uc names. This solution seems closer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it

```
w=(
  '\nEffective URL: %{url_effective}'
  '\nSize: %{size_download}'
  '\nTotal time: %{time_total}'
  '\nRedirect URL: %{redirect_url}'
)
curl -Ss --include --location --config curl.config -w "${w[*]}" icanhazip.com
```

When you do it your way, word splitting is happening, so the `-w` string is split up on each space instead of being passed as a single string.

```
$ set -x

$ : curl $MODE --include --location --config curl.config icanhazip.com
+ : curl -sS -w '"\nEffective' URL: '%{url_effective}' '\nSize:' '%{size_download}' '\nTotal' time: '%{time_total}' '\nRedirect' URL: '%{redirect_url}"' --include --location --config curl.config icanhazip.com
```

Comment: Nice. Do you have any idea why the MODE variable doesn't expand correctly?

Comment: Steven, I don't understand the code in your edit and the 2nd code block. What is the `$ set -x` doing? Second, what is line 2? That looks like my original...